# Laptop Backup Software (Corporate)?

Tags: windows, backup, laptop, cdp

I wondered if any of you who have a fleet of laptops are using anything to back them up, and if so what?

In particular I'm looking for a solution that is totally hands-off once installed i.e. the user doesn't have to do anything, press anything, remember to change something when their domain password changes etc.

Right now we use Druva Insync which I have to say is pretty damned good, however our license is up for renewal in a couple of months so I want to be sure it's the best solution before renewing - the only other vaguely comparable product that I know of is from Atempo but the cost of a SQL Server license is a big problem there.

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system(s) on the laptops? It sound like Windows but you should be specific, rather than leaving it to guesswork.

Comment: Sorry yes, Windows, mix of XP Vista and 7 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Backup Exec 2010 with Desktop/Laptop option.  Easy add if you use Backup Exec already

Answer (score 2):

We use [Iron Mountain's PC Backup](http://www.ironmountain.co.uk/dataprotection/pc/backup.asp), I don't support the back end, so have no idea how good that it, but it's completely seamless from the client.

Comment: I work for Iron Mountain, although not in the division that sells or supports Connected. I have it on my work laptop of course, that's part of the corp package. I also have it on my home machine and have had few problems with it, and it has saved my iTunes catalog from corruption a couple of times. Hey, it's my home machine :-)

Answer (score 1):

We're using [Attix5](http://www.attix5.com/), works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

backuppc, amvar, ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if Atempo can be used with SQL Express.  I say that because I think Atempo is one of the best solutions, with [Microsoft Data Protection Manager 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/SystemCenter/DataProtectionManager/) a close second.

If you do server backups with Backup Exec, than you can use the Desktop and Lapotp Option (DLO).  However, I would not deploy Backup Exec just for DLO.

Comment: Thanks.  AIUI Atempo actually stores the data in SQL though I'll go take another look right now.

DPM 2010 did look like a possibility, I just found the DPM website all over the place between working out what's in 2007 and 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The UK National Health Service in Sussex use Backup exec for their backups...
While I was working for them it seemed to be a very effective solution!